# What is the best way, more straight-forward, way to calculate a modulus operation?

Tags: javascript, java, math, modulo

I'm currently learning Java and JavaScript (alongside HTML and CSS).
I've been struggling with logical and arithmetic operations for a long time as I've never been good at maths in school. My question is : What is the best, more straight-forward (aka with the less steps possible) way to calculate a modulus operation ?

For exemple, here is how a find the result for 38 % 5 :
This is my step-by-step method to find the result.

38 % 5

---

First, I'll divide 38 by 5 :
38 / 5 = 7.6

Here, I'll make sure the result is correct :
7.6 * 5 = 38

I've noticed modulus results oftenly (if not always) have decimals (7.6; 4.333; ...).
Somewhat somehow, I had the idea to make 7 * 5 :
7 * 5 = 35

Good ! So, if I make a last substraction, I should get the modulus, right ? :
38 - 35 = 3

Let's check it, and it's correct ! :
38 % 5 = 3
Hence, I found the result of 38 % 5.

---

Now, I'm not particularly sure that this is the proper way to calculate a modulus by yourself (aka by using step-by-step operations on a calculator rather than using a Java / JavaScript operation) but that's how I do and it works. I could stop the thinking now and roll with it but I want to be sure that I'm doing the right thing before taking a bad habit.

My question is simple : Does my method will systematically work or not ?
If not, what should I do ? How should I calculate this simple operation ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using the modulus operator `%`?

Comment: Just make sure to round the number down before subtracting.

Comment: Are you asking if JavaScript is reliable? Yes, it will always return the same result from `38%5`: `3`. Which is correct, mathematically.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, even though I've figured it out pretty much randomly.
So, I'm doing this correctly ?
I have no doubt the computer will always be right and viable, my question is about making a modulus operation by yourself (should you be using your mind or a calculator) and make sure I understand what a modulus is and how it works.

Comment: ["The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6) produces a result value such that (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)

Comment: A great resource for learning JavaScript, especially for beginners, is MDN. That way you'll read stuff up, instead of figuring it out randomly. In this case: [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).

Comment: Why do you need to calculate modulus this way?

Comment: Put differently: the most straightforward way to calculate modulus operation in JavaScript is using the modulus operator: `a % b`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, MDN is a very good source of information. I'll check what they say about it and the question can be considered solved on my part.

Answer (score -1):

The way you're doing it is fine if you have to do it by hand for some reason. The modulus operator is just finding the remainder of division with numbers A and B. So, as you said, if you have a decimal, remove it and multiply those two numbers together, then subtract the result from the original dividend and the result will be the modulus of the two numbers.

A few examples

9 % 3 = 0 because 3 goes into 9 equally 3 times leaving us with no remainder.

12 % 5 = 2, 5 goes into 12 twice with a remainder of 2 or using your method:

12/5=2.4 -> 2*5=10 -> 12-10=2 so 12%5=2.